# Qu'est-ce qu'un « arroi de dentelles » ?

Tags: sens, littérature, poésie

L'une de [fables](http://www.ecole-mollkirch.com/docs/poesie/fable1.pdf) de [Maurice Carême](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Car%C3%AAme) commence par la strophe

> En arroi de dentelles,
>   La très noble Isabelle
>   Traversait la forêt.
>   Un loup maigre paraît
>   Qui se jette sur elle.

Qu'est-ce qu'un **arroi de dentelles**?

- *arroi*: [train, équipage accompagnant un grand personnage](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/arroi/5465?q=arroi#381051)
- *dentelle*: [tissu ajouré](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dentelle/23638?q=dentelle#23519)

Les deux définitions me semblent assez incompatibles.Le sens de la phrase m'avait fait penser qu'un arroi serait l'un des éléments de l'habit de la princesse.

Comment: l'équipage est d'abord ce qui l'équipe, c'est à dire ses habits par exemple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il faut définir *arroi* avec le sens que les mots avaient au XVIIe siècle :

- *[Train](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/train) :* Suite d'êtres animés ou de choses formant un ensemble ou fonctionnant ensemble.
- *[Équipage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9quipage) :* Ensemble des vêtements et accessoires adaptés à une profession ou une activité donnée.
- *[Appareil](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appareil) :* [En parlant d'une pers.] Ensemble des apprêts (en particulier la tenue, la toilette, etc.) qui contribuent à donner à une personne une apparence extérieure généralement très favorable.

Il y a donc une suite de dentelles qui sont parfaitement assemblées pour vêtir une princesse et la faire apparaître sous son meilleur jour.